# Display Previous YTD Value member on MDX for SSAS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx

YTD is working fine but I need a value from previous year. The following Previous YTD only displays the total previous years amount. For example of august 2013, YTD display the total YTD amount from January to August in 2013 and Previous YTD should display the total YTD amount from January to August 2012.

**YTD**

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[YTD Amount]
 AS AGGREGATE(YTD(), [Measures].[Amount]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Amount] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'TF - BU Transaction';
```

**Previous YTD**

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Prev YTD Amount]
 AS (ParallelPeriod(
   [MF - Time].[Year - Month].[Year]
   ,1
   ,[MF - Time].[Year - Month].CurrentMember)
  , [Measures].[YTD Amount]), 
FORMAT_STRING = "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00", 
NON_EMPTY_BEHAVIOR = { [Amount] }, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'TF - BU Transaction';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use your year to date calculation in your PYTD calculation because you need the YTD outside of the parallell period.

Try:

```
MEMBER [Measures].[Prev YTD Amount] AS
    SUM(
            YTD(
                ParallelPeriod(
                    [MF - Time].[Year - Month].[Year], 
                    1, 
                    [MF - Time].[Year - Month].CurrentMember
                )
            ),
            [Measures].[Amount]
        )
```

Source: [www.bidn.com/blogs/cprice1979/ssas/2473/fun-with-mdx-ndash-part-3-ytd-and-prior-ytd-calculations](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/cprice1979/ssas/2473/fun-with-mdx-ndash-part-3-ytd-and-prior-ytd-calculations)